# What Hardy's inequality is this?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

During a seminar the other day, the lecturer mentioned a Hardy's inequality $|x|^{-2} \le K(1-\Delta)$, where $K$ is a constant and $\Delta$ is the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. I searched for Hardy's inequality on google, and I found a lot of inequalities under this name, but none of them seems to match the prescription of mine. What is this Hardy's inequality the lecturer was referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a Hardy type inequality. Notice that here it is written as an operator inequality, but you can of course also write it as an integral inequality just by using the definition of positive operator ($A\leq B\iff \forall \varphi, \langle\varphi, A\varphi \rangle \leq \langle\varphi, B\varphi \rangle$). This gives, for any $\varphi : \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb C$,
$$
\int \frac{|\varphi(x)|^2}{|x|^2}\,\mathrm dx \leq K \int |\varphi(x)|^2+|\nabla\varphi(x)|^2\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Is it closer to what you know? I think the first term on the right-hand side is actually not needed, but not sure (perhaps it depends on the domain?).

Comment: The first term is indeed unneeded on $\mathbb{R}^d$. More generally, Hardy's inequality refers to $\int |\phi(x)|^p/|x|^p dx \leq K_{n,p} \int |\nabla\phi(x)|^p dx$, for $d\geq 2$ and $1 \leq p < d$ and the integrals are over $\mathbb{R}^d$. There is a version for domains with boundary as well.

Comment: I suppose the domain of $\psi$ is the Sobolev space $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$?

Comment: If not, the right-hand side is just infinite ... but yes, the domain of the operator $1-\Delta$ is $H^1$.

Comment: @GyuEunLee, yes there are a lot of possible generalizations, power $p$, fractional Sobolev spaces ... it also works for $p>d$ with some conditions of $\varphi$ being $0$ at $0$.